# Find index in nested array objects , check if the data is the same value

Tags: javascript, arrays, nested

I have some data like this

```
let dataCart = [
  {
    "id": "001",
    "name": "Product 1",
    "price": 23,
    "image": "images1.jpg",
    "group_option": null,
    "qty": 1,
    "note": ""
  },
  {
    "id": "002",
    "name": "Product 2",
    "price": 25,
    "image": "images2.JPG",
    "group_option": null,
    "qty": 1,
    "note": "Lorem Ipsum something"
  },
  {
    "id": "003",
    "name": "Product 3",
    "price": 100,
    "image": "Images3.jpg",
    "group_option": [
      {
        "id": "0122",
        "name": "Option Name 2",
        "option": [
          {
            "name": "Oreo",
            "price": 15
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": "0124",
        "name": "Option Name 4",
        "option": [
          {
            "name": "Chocolate",
            "price": 10
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "qty": 1,
    "note": ""
  },
  {
    "id": "003",
    "name": "Product 3",
    "price": 100,
    "image": "Images3.jpg",
    "group_option": [
      {
        "id": "0124",
        "name": "Option Name 4",
        "option": [
          {
            "name": "Chocolate",
            "price": 10
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "qty": 1,
    "note": ""
  },
  {
    "id": "0047",
    "name": "Name Product 47",
    "price": 45,
    "image": "Images47.JPG",
    "group_option": [
      {
        "id": "00341",
        "name": "Size",
        "option": [
          {
            "name": "Random Name",
            "price": 7
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "qty": 1,
    "note": ""
  }
]
```

and data input/incoming like this

```
let inputData = {
    "id": "003",
    "name": "Product 3",
    "price": 100,
    "image": "Images3.jpg",
    "group_option": [
      {
        "id": "0122",
        "name": "Option Name 2",
        "option": [
          {
            "name": "Oreo",
            "price": 15
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": "0124",
        "name": "Option Name 4",
        "option": [
          {
            "name": "Chocolate",
            "price": 10
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "qty": 1,
    "note": ""
  }
```

What i'm try to do is filter/find index, if `dataCart.id === inputData.id` then check if `group_option` is the same as incoming data, but i don't know how to compare the nested of `group_option`

my expecting is when `inputData` is exist or same whole value then `dataCart.qty + inputData.qty`,

but if `inputData` doesn't exist or not equal `dataCart` arrays, for example like

```
let inputData = {
    "id": "003",
    "name": "Product 3",
    "price": 100,
    "image": "Images3.jpg",
    "group_option": [
      {
        "id": "0122",
        "name": "Option Name 2",
        "option": [
          {
            "name": "Oreo",
            "price": 15
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": "0124",
        "name": "Option Name 4",
        "option": [
          {
            "name": "Chocolate",
            "price": 10
          },
          {
            "name": "Jelly",
            "price": 5
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "qty": 1,
    "note": ""
  }
```

then add new to the `dataCart` arrays

Comment: Is it enough to compare the group_option ids? e.g. if the incoming data had group_options with id 0122 and 0124, and so did the existing data could you say that the group_options matched? If the group_options were 0122 and 0124 for one set, and 0122, 0124 and 0126 for another, presumably that would not count as a match?

Comment: @BenStephens I just edited my question, it's not enough to compare just group_option id, because that possible it has more than one data in option list part..

yes, you're right, if the group_option has different either it's from id or from option list, that would not count as a match

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is quite what you're looking for, but the idea here is to create a string for a group_option that would be identical to a matching group_option (without being identical to a non-matching one) so that they can be compared in a fairly straight forward way.

```js
let dataCart = [{"id":"001","name":"Product 1","price":23,"image":"images1.jpg","group_option":null,"qty":1,"note":""},{"id":"002","name":"Product 2","price":25,"image":"images2.JPG","group_option":null,"qty":1,"note":"Lorem Ipsum something"},{"id":"003","name":"Product 3","price":100,"image":"Images3.jpg","group_option":[{"id":"0122","name":"Option Name 2","option":[{"name":"Oreo","price":15}]},{"id":"0124","name":"Option Name 4","option":[{"name":"Chocolate","price":10}]}],"qty":1,"note":""},{"id":"003","name":"Product 3","price":100,"image":"Images3.jpg","group_option":[{"id":"0124","name":"Option Name 4","option":[{"name":"Chocolate","price":10}]}],"qty":1,"note":""},{"id":"0047","name":"Name Product 47","price":45,"image":"Images47.JPG","group_option":[{"id":"00341","name":"Size","option":[{"name":"Random Name","price":7}]}],"qty":1,"note":""}];

let inputData1 = {"id":"003","name":"Product 3","price":100,"image":"Images3.jpg","group_option":[{"id":"0122","name":"Option Name 2","option":[{"name":"Oreo","price":15}]},{"id":"0124","name":"Option Name 4","option":[{"name":"Chocolate","price":10}]}],"qty":1,"note":""};

let inputData2 = {"id":"003","name":"Product 3","price":100,"image":"Images3.jpg","group_option":[{"id":"0122","name":"Option Name 2","option":[{"name":"Oreo","price":15}]},{"id":"0124","name":"Option Name 4","option":[{"name":"Chocolate","price":10},{"name": "Jelly","price": 5}]}],"qty":1,"note":""};

const option_identity = (option) =>
  option.id + '_' +
    option.option
      .map( (opt) => opt.name )
      .sort()
      .join('_');

const group_option_identity = (group_option) =>
  (group_option ?? [])
    .map(option_identity)
    .sort()
    .join('-');

const matching_items = (item1, item2) =>
  item1.id === item2.id ?
    group_option_identity(item1.group_option) === group_option_identity(item2.group_option) :
    false;

const find_match_in_cart = (cart, item) =>
  cart.find( (cart_item) => matching_items(cart_item, item) ) || null;

const match1 = find_match_in_cart(dataCart, inputData1);
const match2 = find_match_in_cart(dataCart, inputData2);

console.log(match1?.id);
console.log(match2?.id);

console.log(group_option_identity(match1.group_option));
console.log(group_option_identity(inputData1.group_option));
console.log(group_option_identity(inputData2.group_option));
```